# jQuery $(document).keydown() issues

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am currently working on a web app which requires a standard desktop application menu bar. I have started to work on the menu bar and have the layout sorted.

Unfortunatrly, the client wants to have access keys (such as Alt+F) loads the "File" menu. When the Alt key is pressed, I want to show the access keys. I currently have the following jQuery code to handle this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 18) { alt_shifter = true; $('.access_key').css({ textDecoration: 'underline' }); }
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 18) { alt_shifter = false; $('.access_key').css({ textDecoration: 'none' }); }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, as you'll see on the jsFiddle, for some reason in Google Chrome, when pressing Alt, the keys are underlined, then normalised on keyup. However, pressing Alt again does nothing, until the next time it's pressed. It's almost as if once the underline has been done and `keyup` has been fired, it does not register the keyup until it's pressed again.

Here's the jsFiddle demo > http://jsfiddle.net/Ht2wD/

Any help would be most gratefully received!

Comment: It works for me - underline goes on and off each time ALT is pressed and released. Chrome 13.0.782.220 on MacOS 10.7.1

Comment: @Alnitak - Strange, it doesn't work for me on exact same version of Chrome under Windows 7.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with 13.0.782.220 on Windows.

Comment: yeap, try here. the problem exist.

Comment: Agreed. The `keydown` event does not fire at all every other press of the `alt` key. It works as normal for all other keys I've tried.

Comment: Just as a side note, you can also check directly if the alt key was pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/6fFNU/

Comment: Can one of you experiencing the weirdness file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/ with as much detail as possible? The behavior shouldn't be distinct across platforms.

Comment: @all I believe the issue is with the browser (and not a real issue at all).  What happens is when you press alt, your event is fired but because this is a universal system command, the browser itself also handles it.  Chrome doesn't have a readily visible file menu, but if it did, I assume it would show the access keys there.  The next keypress is then captured by the browser.  If you just press alt again, nothing happens and focus is returned to the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I altered the code to include **e.preventDefault();** right before the keyCode check and it seemed to work.  Here's the website that helped me arrive at that answer http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 5):

try with this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ht2wD/14/

using `e.preventDefault();` work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your updated Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ht2wD/13/

This lovely issue is fixed by adding `e.preventDefault()`.  If I had to guess, it's because the ALT key is also captured by the browser itself and is displaying its own highlighted menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.keyCode == 18) { alt_shifter = true; $('.access_key').css({ textDecoration: 'underline' }); }
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.keyCode == 18) { alt_shifter = false; $('.access_key').css({ textDecoration: 'none' }); }
    });
});
```