# Jquery second keydown not detected by $(document).keydown()

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown

I would like to use create two keyboard shorcuts. The first one (`keyCode == 80`) works but not the second one. I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445151/jquery-document-keydown-issues) but without success.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #FFC0CB;">

    <p><red> Ctrl + P = 1 color // Ctrl + I = 2 colors</red></p>
    <p id="log"> </p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.warning-bar:first',parent.document).hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).keydown(function(e){
      // 80=p / 81=q  / 73=i  / 77=m /  cf http://keycode.info/    
      e.preventDefault();
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.altKey && e.keyCode == 80){    
          $('#log').html('you pressed Ctrl + p');
           google.script.run.added();
            }
       if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.altKey &&  e.keyCode == 77){    
          $('#log').html('you pressed Ctrl + m');
           google.script.run.modified();          
      }
      });


    });

    </script>


}

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for testing?

Comment: @Darkisa, I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the correct results using both ctrl + shift + alt + m and ctrl + shift + alt + p using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/7acakxeg/

I only removed the google script and `$('.warning-bar:first',parent.document).hide();`